# What is the correct way to dynamically pass a list or variable into a SQL cell in a spark databricks notebook in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

This seems like it should be straight forward to do however have not been able to get this working cleanly for long lists as yet:

Previous cell:

```
val myList = List(111,222)
```

Current Cell:

```
%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;

CREATE TABLE myTable AS
    SELECT * FROM datalake.someTable t
      WHERE t.someColumn IN myList --correctly parse the list here
```

One solution might be to use a widget, but that seems to be for strings, and for long lists would be limited by max string length? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register an user-defined function containing your variable. User-defined functions can be passed to SQL cells as explained [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html#call-the-udf-in-spark-sq0)

Your code will be, in your scala cell:

```scala
val myList = List(111, 222)
val myListUdf = () => myList
spark.udf.register("my_list", myListUdf)
```

And then, you can perform you query in your SQL cell:

```sql
%sql

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;

CREATE TABLE myTable AS
    SELECT * FROM datalake.someTable t
      WHERE array_contains(my_list(), t.someColumn)
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent appreciated (+1 already) couple of additional parameters just in my particular case to the question I should have been clearer on - the column is of surrogate_ids which can be long integers eg: List(2182361060000, ...) which caused an int too large issue, or a type missmatch if defined as List(11111111111L, ...). 
The list will be created by something like this:
val myList = someTable.select("surr_id").collect().map(_(0)).toList

Which when I try to register that as a UDF it throws an error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported ?

Comment: First Point, for converting your column to Long, you can use CAST SQL method, something like `CAST(surrogate_ids AS BIGINT)`. Second Point, for your array, after your `collect` you use `.map(_(0))` that create a list of Any, not serializable by spark. The solution is to use `.map(_.getLong(0))` instead. Hope it can help

Comment: Thanks Vincent much appreciated!!

Comment: Hi Vincent, sorry I thought it was running fine there, but .map(_.getLong(0)) threw: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long ?

Comment: You can either cast your BigDecimal to long before collecting data: `someTable.select("surr_id").withColumn("surr_id", col("surr_id").cast("Long")).collect().map(_.getLong(0))`. If you do so, you will need to import `col` function with `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col`. Or you can cast to BigDecimal after collect: `.collect().map(_.getAs[java.math.BigDecimal](0))`. It depends if you want a list of `Long` (first solution) or a list of `BigDecimal` (second solution)

Comment: Thanks again Vincent appreciated!!

Comment: Hi Vincent! There's a last piece to this in my specific use case, I am sure you'd know how to resolve it! I have put on another question so more credit if answered and so more people can find that topic & answer separately, if you did have a moment free to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64645788/in-a-scala-notebook-on-apache-spark-databricks-how-do-you-correctly-cast-an-arra   that would be hugely appreciated! Thanks Vincent!